# Virtual box guest addition breaks after kernel upgrade

Tags: upgrade, kernel, virtualbox, guest-additions

I have an Ubuntu box installed over VirtualBox with Windows 7 as host. I installed guest additions in it and was working perfectly as expected.

Suddenly, one day VirtualBox complained that guest additions are not installed (possibly after an upgrade). I had to reinstall guest additions all the way again.

Is this because of kernel upgrades from Ubuntu? A new kernel needs a reinstall of guest addition?

Answer (score 1):

No, generally it doesn't require. `dkms` takes care of the upgradation.

Please have a look here - [How do I keep guest additions working in virtual box after updates?](https://askubuntu.com/q/58131/35775)

However, some users report even after dkms installation the problem remains.If it is happening with you, I would like to point to the below answer.

First uninstall using `sudo /opt/[VboxAddonsFolder]/uninstall.sh`
Then follow https://askubuntu.com/a/99479/35775

You can also read other answers in the question - [How do I install Guest Additions in a VirtualBox VM?](https://askubuntu.com/q/22743/35775)

Comment: If this is happening with me, do I have to uninstall and reinstall guest additions every time a kernel upgrade happens?

Comment: First try the solution provided in the answer & the links. By following those steps, with kernel upgrade the installation should be done automatically. If those are not working, yes you have to do manually & it would be a bug too.